# How to get youtube url from html code in react native

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using API to my react native project.

I have problem when try to get youtube url from html.

HTML Code

```
<p><em><u style="text-decoration:underline"><strong>Đặt mua 12 lượt rửa trọn gói&nbsp;tính tiền 10 lượt.</strong></u></em></p><p>TMCARe với đội ngũ nhân viên thật thà và cẩn thận sẽ mang lại sự hài lòng cho khách hàng. TMCARe áp dụng quy trình rửa xe với tiêu chí: Cẩn thận, tỉ mỉ và sạch sẽ. Sử dụng khăn sạch, mỗi xe một bộ khăn, nước rửa xe Đức an toàn và bóng bẩy!</p><p>####</p><p>Thông tin chi tiết về dịch vụ</p><p><iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/dglnN8Mx0k4" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" width="560" height="314" frameborder="0"></iframe></p>
```

My question:

- How to get "www.youtube.com/embed/dglnN8Mx0k4" from above code.

Many thanks

Comment: Have you already tried something?

Comment: Thanks, i try to find in google and stackoverflow, example function youtube_parser(url){
    var regExp = /^.*((youtu.be\/)|(v\/)|(\/u\/\w\/)|(embed\/)|(watch\?))\??v?=?([^#&?]*).*/;
    var match = url.match(regExp);
    return (match&&match[7].length==11)? match[7] : false;
} but it is not work for all html code

Comment: I guess you didn't even read that regex, since it contains "youtu.be" so it cannot clearly match your url.

Comment: Maybe `((?:www\.)?youtube\.(?:be|com)\S+?)(?=[\s"])` is what you need?  [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cd6Ouk/1)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @horcrux.
After read your answer, i try to find the solution.

```
const youtube_parser_from_body = (item) => {
            let list_youtube_id = [];
            try {
                let body_html = item.body_html;
                if (body_html !== null) {
                    let body_list = body_html.split('<iframe ');
                    for (const item of body_list) {
                        if (item.includes("src=\"//www.youtube.com/")) {
                            let iframe_html_list = item.split("</iframe>");
                            let first_element = iframe_html_list[0];
                            first_element = first_element.replace("src=\"//", "");
                            let first_element_list = first_element.split('\"');
                            let first_link = first_element_list[0]
                            var regExp = /^.*((www.youtube.com\/)|(v\/)|(\/u\/\w\/)|(embed\/)|(watch\?))\??v?=?([^#&?]*).*/;
                            var match = first_link.match(regExp);
                            let youtube_id = (match && match[7].length == 11) ? match[7] : false;
                            list_youtube_id.push(youtube_id);
                        }
                    }

                }
            } catch (e) {

            }
           
            return list_youtube_id;
        }
```

Thanks @Ketan Malhotra, your solution only work if only one link in body_html, if have more link, it will make result like picuture:
[image: problems for Ketan Malhotra code if have more link]

Answer (score -1):

To grow as a programmer, it's necessary to try a solution yourself before asking others. And if you have tried a solution, tell us what you have tried, so that we can help you better and tell us what you were doing wrong.

Nevertheless, I see you have tried using regex. Clearly, you haven't explored how regex works much. To help you with that, go ahead and use a tool like https://regex101.com/

I was able to filter out your video link on regex101 like this: https://regex101.com/r/AEspDU/1

Sounds like this is working. It currently returns an array of all youtube URLs found in a given string:

```js
function youtube_parser(url){
  var regExp = /(?:youtube\.com\/(?:[^\/]+\/.+\/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)\/|.*?[?&]v=)|youtu\.be\/)([^"&?\/\s]{11})/gi;
  var matches = url.match(regExp);
  return matches ? matches : false;
}

var htmlCode = '<p><em><u style="text-decoration:underline"><strong>Đặt mua 12 lượt rửa trọn gói&nbsp;tính tiền 10 lượt.</strong></u></em></p><p>TMCARe với đội ngũ nhân viên thật thà và cẩn thận sẽ mang lại sự hài lòng cho khách hàng. TMCARe áp dụng quy trình rửa xe với tiêu chí: Cẩn thận, tỉ mỉ và sạch sẽ. Sử dụng khăn sạch, mỗi xe một bộ khăn, nước rửa xe Đức an toàn và bóng bẩy!</p><p>####</p><p>Thông tin chi tiết về dịch vụ</p><p><iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/dglnN8Mx0k4" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" width="560" height="314" frameborder="0"></iframe></p>';

console.log(youtube_parser(htmlCode));
```